November 2024 Photo Competition: Snow
The topic is "snow", so photos containing snow (on the ground, falling from the sky, etc.).
The contest will end at the end of November (UTC time). The following rules apply:

Up to three photos per answer. Photos in the same answer should be related.
You can make up to three posts (attempts).
Do not delete posts if you don't get votes: you posted it, stand by it. (You have two more attempts if your first one doesn't work out.)
All submissions should have a line with when and where the photo(s) was/were taken, along with a description of the subject.
The photo has to be taken by the person who posted it, or by a travel partner (needs to be named).
Keep it nice, CoC-compliant, non-offensive, and suitable for work.
If you have people recognizable in the photo, you must either (a) have their permission to post the photo or (b) make them unrecognizable.
If you disagree with a photo, please consider leaving a comment on it or bringing it up in chat. For the purposes of judging, only upvotes will be considered; downvotes will not affect the score of the photo.
The photo may have been taken any time.
If there is no tie for the highest number of upvotes at the end of the month, the winner will be announced then; if there is, the voting period may extend beyond the month.
If you'd like to suggest a theme for a future photo competition, please add it to the list of possible photo competition topics. Also, you can join us in chat to help us make the decision on which topic to choose.


Maihaugen, Lillehammer, Norway, January 9th, 2021.



Congratulations, these photos had the most upvotes when the competition closed!

We had a nice cold January in 2021, and the snowflakes were extra pretty, so I took a few shots with a macro lens on my phone. Really small depth of field so it was tricky.




This should have been the winning photo in my view, so my virtual prize is for you.

Oh, thank you so much @Willeke

Scharnitz, Austria, January 27th, 2019


I took this photo a few years ago (2022?) in Washington, USA.


Both pictures were taken in Østerdalen, Norway, January 1st, 2021.




Cat in a Colorado snowstorm, circa 2003.

I went on an Alaska cruise last year.  There wasn't much snow, except when we got near the glaciers.
These photos are in Yakutat & Disenchantment Bays, and I believe the Hubbard Glacier.  May 2023.



You win the virtual prize this month, congratulations!

@cocomac Thanks!

It's snowing over farmland in UK in February 2009.

